# chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener doesn't work in content script

Tags: javascript

In chrome extension, i try to send a message from background script to content script. I don't get messages in content script. Where am going wrong? Here's the background.js

```
function createAlarm() {
   chrome.alarms.create('bookcab', {
          periodInMinutes: 1
   });
}

chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener(function(alarm) {
    if (alarm.name === 'bookcab') {
       var url = 'http://cab/';
       chrome.tabs.create({ url:url, active: true });
       chrome.tabs.query({active:true}, function(tabs){
          chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {"message": "sample_msg"});
        });
    }
});

createAlarm();
```

And the content_script.js has the following code,

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request,sender,sendresponse) {
    if( request.message === "sample_msg" ) {
       console.log('message from content script');                     
    }
  }
);
```

Here's the manifest.json if it matters

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name":"bookcab",
    "version":"0.1",
    "background": {
        "scripts":["background.js"]
    },
    "permissions": [
        "alarms",
        "tabs"
    ],
    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches":["<all_urls>"],
        "js": ["content_script.js"],
        "run_at" : "document_end"
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have included a tab load completion before sending message to content script.

**WAIT FOR TAB TO BE FULLY LOADED**

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {          
   if (changeInfo.status == 'complete') {   
      chrome.tabs.query({active: true}, function(tabs){
         chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {"message": "sample_msg"});
      }
   }
});
```